# how can I sandbox user areas?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, folder

What if I was to create a SP2013 document library that contains one folder for every user? Users can only view and edit their own folders. The idea is that every user would have their own sandbox area/folder.

The problem is that there are 700+ users. So that’d be 700+ folders.

Are folders the right approach here?

Thx

Comment: Typically this is what I advocate My Sites/One Drive for Business for, their personal sites are their own sandbox.

Comment: Excellent. This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this is what I advocate My Sites/One Drive for Business for, their personal sites are their own sandbox as they have site collection administrator rights. They can create their own libraries, subsites, experiment as they want.